# What to do for the client to release us from project?

Tags: visa, knowledge-transfer, onsite

My friend and I are working for a client from my company since almost last 10 years on a big project.

No one else know the work we did, so we will be called anytime to look into any issue in the project.

Recently we got our visas and informed client to give us the budget for onsite or release us from the project.

Last time when asked he said to provide knowledge transfers to our recently recruited replacement resources. ( either to release us or to give onsite he just told to give KTs to support in offshore)

Now he is saying that he dont have the confidence that new persons will handle the projects and also not given the onsite budget.

The situation is like he wont release us or give the onsite budget.

We are struggling because of his selfish behaviour, please suggest what to do in this situation to travel to onsite?

Comment: I guess comments did not get migrated. Please add a lot more details so we can answer your question here. What country are you in? What country do you want to go to? What exactly is your visa, is it dependent on your contract? What does your contract say about this? Are you in any way involved in picking or training your replacements? What is a KT?

Comment: Also see past questions about customers who continue asking for support after the project is over. TL:DR: You owe them exactly what the contract and law says you owe them. Anything beyond that is voluntary, and unless you have a reason for giving away your time you should be charging for it under a new contract

Comment: 1. Where are you right now? 2. Which country is your employer in? 3. Which country is your client in? 4. Is your client _your_ client (working as a contractor) or your employers client? 5. Where is "onsite"? 6. You have a visa for which place? 7. Do you want to get a job with a different employer? 8. Why would your client be releasing you and not your employer? 9. How do you post a question that doesn't get downvoted because lots of relevant information is missing?

Comment: 10 years is a long time to work for a company. I assume you're not a slave. If your employer doesn't want to deny the client's request, maybe search and find a new employer to work with.

Answer (score 4):

What are your *contractual* obligations? If you have been on it for 10 years then I would assume you are either an employee or are paid a regular retainer or a daily/hourly rate. In any case, there ought to be a legal way to discharge your obligations.

Make a list of your client's concerns and work through them one by one until they (or you) feel you have done enough. I expect you will want to decide how much it is worth to you to stay involved or to walk away. If you can't resolve that amicably then maybe you need a lawyer.

Answer (score -1):

Selfish behavior? Well, that kind of thinking will likely interfere with you negotiating an agreement that maximizes mutual benefits and overcomes barriers. It is clear what you want but you are silent on how this will benefit the other party seated at the table. What it will do, bringing offshore employees onsite, is increase their costs like 400%+.

So the benefits of that, so you can exercise your visas and explore a new country, need to outweigh their exponential increase in costs.

You have some leverage here but no one is indispensable. Everyone can be replaced.

If you are still under contract, and you negotiated no termination clause for convenience, you need to continue to perform or face litigation and likely a ton of penalties and legal costs, including theirs.

Their behavior is not selfish. Their business does not exist to get you to a new country. They owe you nothing except payment for services rendered pursuant to your negotiated contract. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: "He won't release us". That's likely India, and the problem isn't that OP thinks he is irreplaceable, the problem is that OP wants to leave and the client thinks he is irreplaceable.

Comment: David, their behaviour is absolutely selfish. You explained why they ought to be selfish, but they are selfish.

Comment: @gnasher729, if he's under contract, the contract to which the OP agreed is not releasing him. The other party is simply holding him to the agreement in which he participated. What selfish behavior is going on here? Now, if he is a slave and the slave master won't release, then, yeah, sure, selfish. Is that legal in India?

Comment: @DavidEspina In theory, no, that kind of behaviour is not legal in India; a company must honour a request to resign and provide the appropriate [relieving letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relieving-letter) so the employee can legally obtain another job. In practice, unscrupulous companies will threaten to withhold the relieving letter, at which point the employee cannot obtain employment with another reputable employer, and the Indian courts will not remedy this situation efficiently.

Comment: He used the word "client," not "employer." Whatever weird issues one faces in India to resign, this OP is not about that...at least through implication from the word client. So if his company is contracted with the client, the client holding his company to the contract is not selfish behavior, it is normal and appropriate behavior.

Comment: Selfish = looking after my own interests first. I will act selfish when it's important to me. Doesn't mean its bad in any way, but it is selfish.

Comment: Quite a slice you're taking. During original negotiations, mutual benefits and compromises were made. Agreement was had. The OP is pulling away. That sir is selfish. The response is simply a legal one and the right one.